# Command docker-compose (re)build does not build fresh instance of container

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose

I created `./docker/app/Dockerfile` with sth like this:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
(...)
```

My docker-compose:

```
  app:
    build: './docker/app/'
    image: php:7.3-apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
    (...)
```

I'm trying to build clean instance of my container. I wish it will look like first build (I want to test if my Dockerfile is ok and will install all required packages).
But after making command:
`docker-compose build app` I see warnings like:

```
Module rewrite already enabled
warning: pdo_mysql (pdo_mysql.so) is already loaded!
```

Commands `docker-compose build --force-rm app` and `docker-compose build --force-rm --no-cache app` works the same. Packages installed once still persists and my Dockerfile's commands has no sense during the build.

So I have 2 questions:

1) How to build new clean version of my app container from scratch?

2) What commands `docker-compose build` and  `docker-compose build --force-rm` are for if they don't build new image?

Answer (score 1):

try to reforce the build using:

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate
```

or delete every thing before you build:

```
docker-compose rm
docker image prune
```